# WPF - how to databind multiple listbox items from the same dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, data-binding, listbox

I have 4 listbox items that are containing checkbox items. I am trying to bind them from the same Dataset but it seems I am not doing it right. When I bind them this way only 4th listbox item displays items names, the rest of them are only displaying blank checkboxes.

Also I would like to know if I bind checkboxes this way, how do I later access to ID values from database that are selected (since I only set Content and I didn't set selectedValuePath or something like that)?

Here is my code below:

XML

```
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="141,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="307" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1"  Content="{Binding NacinGrejanja}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Label Content="Tip Objekta:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,323,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="141,323,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="307">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" Content="{Binding TipObjekta}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Label Content="Opis Objekta:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox3" ItemsSource ="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="142,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="307">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox3" Content="{Binding OpisObjekta}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Label Content="Dodatno:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,437,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox4" ItemsSource ="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="142,437,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="307">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox4" Content="{Binding Dodatno}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

C#

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dataset1 ds= new Dataset1 ();
        GrejanjeTableAdapter gta = new GrejanjeTableAdapter();
        TipObjektaTableAdapter tta = new TipObjektaTableAdapter();
        OpisObjektaTableAdapter ota = new OpisObjektaTableAdapter();
        DodatnoTableAdapter dta = new DodatnoTableAdapter();
        gta.Fill(ds.Grejanje);
        tta.Fill(ds.TipObjekta);
        ota.Fill(ds.OpisObjekta);
        dta.Fill(ds.Dodatno);
        this.DataContext = ds.Grejanje;
        this.DataContext = ds.TipObjekta;
        this.DataContext = ds.OpisObjekta;
        this.DataContext = ds.Dodatno;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
    this.DataContext = ds.Grejanje;
    this.DataContext = ds.TipObjekta;
    this.DataContext = ds.OpisObjekta;
    this.DataContext = ds.Dodatno;
```

You should try this:

```
    listbox1.ItemsSource = ds.Grejanje;
    listbox2.ItemsSource = ds.TipObjekta;
    listbox3.ItemsSource = ds.OpisObjekta;
    listbox4.ItemsSource = ds.Dodatno;
```

And you won't need the `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` on the `ListBox` items.

To get the selected items, you need to bind the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` item to an `IsChecked` boolean property, like this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" IsChecked={Binding IsSelected} Content="{Binding NacinGrejanja}"/>
```

If `NacinGrejanja` doesn't contain an `IsChecked` property, then you should wrap it with a class that does contain it.

The ID for `NacinGrejanja` should be included inside the instance, so you won't have any issue getting the ID of the selected items. If it's not, then again wrap with a class that does.

Comment: It worked but it didn't show me the text of checkBox items without I put  ItemsSource="{Binding}" in ListBox. Also I am not sure that I understood what you mean for ID of NacinGrejanja?

Comment: Regarding the ID thing, i was answering your question "how do I later access to ID values from database that are selected"

Comment: Hi again, I am still struggling with how to check if there is any checkbox is selected and if it is to get the values from database. Could I please ask you to look at this new topic I have opened: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40452039/5721684 . Thank you