# WPF - How to read values from checkbox items that are inside listbox item and bindied with database?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox

I am building an app that will return data from database based on the items that are checked on check box. I have successfully displayed data from database by binding the data. Like this:

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="141,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="307" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"  Content="{Binding NacinGrejanja}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

C#:

```
       private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dataset1 ds= new Dataset1 ();
        GrejanjeTableAdapter gta = new GrejanjeTableAdapter();
        gta.Fill(ds.Grejanje);
        listbox1.DataContext = ds.Grejanje;
    }
```

But I am unable to figure out how to extract string values from checked values and then again search for those values in database. I can't access any of the properties for checkBox1 through code.

Also I would want first to check if any of the checkbox items is checked in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following linq:

```
ds.Grejanje.Where(item => item.IsSelected == true);
```

It will return the list of items which are checked.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your answer. This way gives me an error on IsSelected: 'Nekretninko.DataSet.GrejanjeRow' does not contain a definition for 'IsSelected' and no extension method 'IsSelected' accepting a first argument of type 'Nekretninko.DataSet.GrejanjeRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @Adicili Sorry for not replying soon. Above, your `listbox1` is bound to `ds.Grejanje`. And, from your XAML(`IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"`), I have assumed that your items/rows in `ds.Grejanje` is having a property named `IsSelected`. So when I am querying using linq in `ds.Grejanje`, ideally it should not throw the error.

Comment: @Adicili Can you share the properties your items in `ds.Grejanje` are having? Then I would be able to help you better.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure on which properties do you mean. Grejanje is name of the Table in my database and I have created Dataset(ds) for my database.

Comment: @Adicili `ds.Grejanje` would be a `Enumerable`. And it must contain some items. I wanted to know the properties of one item. And, in your XAML what is `IsSelected` in `IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"`? And, which object does `IsSelected` belong to?